# ${relativeFile} fetched by visualstudio / cmake launch json file is not including the backslash

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, cmake, echo

I have configured some tasks for CMake in Visual studio. One of the commands to execute includes the `${relativeFile}` and it is under subdirectory. The fetched result is not including the '/' to separate the directories.

Here is the `tasks.vs.json` file sample:

```
{
  "taskName": "TestTask",
  "appliesTo": "*/",
  "type": "remote",
  "remoteWorkingDirectory": "/home/root/",
  "contextType": "custom",
  "localCopyDirectory": "${workspaceRoot}\\..\\build\\${env.name}\\bin",
  "remoteMachineName": "${env.TARGET_MACHINE}",
  "remoteCopyMethod": "sftp",
  "remoteCopyDirectory": "/tmp/",
  "command": "echo changing permissions for ${relativeFile}",
  "args": ""
}
```

Expected result: `changing permissions for test\test1`

Current Result: `changing permissions for testtest1`

Comment: Is this about the Visual Studio Code text editor, or the full Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Visual studio IDE. I am using Cmake tool within Visual studio 2017. This happens when i try to configure some tasks.